# JMeter - How to open and keep the WebSocket connection alive

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Well, I have a use case where i need to open n number of WebSocket connection with different query params. Example is as below

```
connection 1 - localhost:3000/connect-ws?id=1
connection 2 - localhost:3000/connect-ws?id=2
connection 3 - localhost:3000/connect-ws?id=3
connection {n} - localhost:3000/connect-ws?id={n}
```

I need all these connections to start concurrently and keep them alive.

Can anyone assist on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. As of JMeter 5.6.2 there is no WebSocket support out of the box. You can consider using [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) plugin which provides **WebSocket Open Connection** sampler.
2. Incrementing `id` can be generated using [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function
3. If you want to keep the connection open add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and configure it to pause for the desired duration

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)

In general I don't think that:

- test which does nothing but opening connections makes sense
- test where the system under test and load generator are on the same machine makes sense

so it worth reconsidering your approach